# Prove that there is NO conformal map from the punctured disk D(0,1) = {0 < |z| < 1} to an annulus D(0; r1, r2 ) with r2 > r1 > 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Prove that there is NO conformal map from the punctured disk D o (0, 1) = {0 < |z| < 1} to an annulus D(0; r 1 , r 2 ) with r 2 > r 1 > 0. (Hint: Assume that such a map exists. Show that it must have the analytic continuation F(z) in D(0, 1). Then F(D(0, 1)) = D(0; r 1 , r 2 ) ∪ F(0), so where does F(0) lie in by the Open Mapping Theorem? Together with the fact that if an analytic function has a zero of order N at z 0 , then it is locally an n-to-1 map, what conclusion can you draw from the above?)

Comment: Could you edit the question with the work you have done so far on this problem?